# Bash One Liner: copy template_*.txt to foo_*.txt?

Tags: bash

Say I have three files (template_*.txt):

- template_x.txt
- template_y.txt
- template_z.txt

I want to copy them to three new files (foo_*.txt).

- foo_x.txt
- foo_y.txt
- foo_z.txt

Is there some simple way to do that with one command, e.g.

`cp --enableAwesomeness template_*.txt foo_*.txt`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
for f in template_*.txt; do cp $f foo_${f#template_}; done
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[01:22 PM] matt@Lunchbox:~/tmp/ba$
ls
template_x.txt  template_y.txt  template_z.txt

[01:22 PM] matt@Lunchbox:~/tmp/ba$
for i in template_*.txt ; do mv $i foo${i:8}; done

[01:22 PM] matt@Lunchbox:~/tmp/ba$
ls
foo_x.txt  foo_y.txt  foo_z.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

My preferred way:

```
for f in template_*.txt
do
  cp $f ${f/template/foo}
done
```

The "I-don't-remember-the-substitution-syntax" way:

```
for i in x y z
do
  cp template_$i foo_$
done
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
for file in template_*.txt ; do cp $file `echo $file | sed 's/template_\(.*\)/foo_\1/'` ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything in bash or on cp, but there are simple ways to do this sort of thing using (for example) a perl script:

```
($op = shift) || die "Usage: rename perlexpr [filenames]\n";

for (@ARGV) {
    $was = $_;
    eval $op;
    die $@ if $@;
    rename($was,$_) unless $was eq $_;
}
```

Then:

```
rename s/template/foo/ *.txt
```

Comment: On my debian system, there's a Perl script installed at `/usr/bin/rename` (part of the `perl` package) which does pretty much exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in template_*.txt; do cp -v "$i" "`echo $i | sed 's%^template_%foo_%'`"; done
```

Probably breaks if your filenames have funky characters in them.  Remove the '-v' when (if) you get confidence that it works reliably.

Answer (score 1):

The command `mmv` (available in [Debian](http://packages.debian.org/etch/mmv) or [Fink](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/mmv) or easy to compile yourself) was created precisely for this task. With the plain Bash solution, I always have to look up the documentation about variable expansion. But `mmv` is much simpler to use, quite close to "awesomeness"! ;-)

Your example would be:

```
mcp "template_*.txt" "foo_#1.txt"
```

`mmv` can handle more complex patterns as well and it has some sanity checks, for example, it will make sure none of the files in the destination set appear in the source set (so you can't accidentally overwrite files).

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do it:

```
$ ls template_*.txt | sed -e 's/^template\(.*\)$/cp template\1 foo\1/' | ksh -sx
```

I've always been impressed with the ImageMagick [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) program that does what you expect with image formats:

```
$ convert rose.jpg rose.png
```

It has a sister program that allows batch conversions:

```
$ mogrify -format png *.jpg
```

Obviously these are limited to image conversions, but they have interesting command line  interfaces.